# reading lines until empty line and getting words

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read lines until there is an empty line and then extract first words from the lines.

on each line there is 2 words. word1 and word2.
the number of lines is not known.
but there is an empty line after those word lines.

example input:

```
word1 word2
word11 word22
word111 word222

some other text here
```

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i;
    string line;
    string wrd1[100], wrd2[100];
    for(;getline(cin,line),!line.empty();) {
        for(i=0;i<line.size();i++) {
            if(line[i] == 32) break;
            else wrd1[i] = line[i];
        }
        cout << wrd1 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but the output is in hexadecimal for some reason!

```
0x7fff753dad10
0x7fff753dad10
0x7fff753dad10
```

how do output them normally as they are (word1, word111...) and not in hexadecimal? Or why does it output in hexadecimal anyway?

Comment: `but the output is in hexadecimal for some reason!` because you're outputting a pointer.

Comment: `for(;getline(cin,line),!line.empty();)` might not work the way you want. Check up on the [comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator). it looks to me like the `getline` can fail and `!line.empty()` is still used. In older C++ revisions, this is a big mistake.

Comment: how is it a pointer?

Comment: @OrangeBike Use `std::vector<string> wrd1(100), wrd2(100);` instead of `string wrd1[100], wrd2[100];` Note: A `std::vector<T>` cannot be printed to `std::cout` directly, you need a loop: `for(auto word : wrd1) std::cout << word << std::endl;`

Comment: @OrangeBike _"how is it a pointer?"_ Read the duplicate please.